Java Networking using Sockets logic error . . . somewhere I think
Using java networking and sockets principles built a simple chat app  It uses Java Networking concepts like Java sockets and Server with streams such as bufferedWriter and bufferedReader reader and also  but for some reason after a connection is established and prints "a new user has connected to the group" it dosent print the username nor the messages the user sends afterwards
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ClientHandler implements Runnable {

    /*creating list to store every instance of this classs - clientHandler 
    * also keeping track of all clients so whenever a client sends a message 
    * it can send the same message to each client
    */
    public static ArrayList<ClientHandler> clientHandlers = new ArrayList<>();
    
    //a socket class for establishing a connection between the client and the server
    private Socket socket;

    //a bufferedReader for reading/revieving data(in form of messages) that have been sent from the client 
    private BufferedReader bufferedReader;

    //a bufferedWriter form sending messages to other clients
    private BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;

    //a username to represent each user (ClientHandler object)
    private String clientUserName;

    public ClientHandler(Socket socket){
        //Setting up class properties
        try{
            this.socket = socket;
            /*Using a 'character stream' OutputStreamWriter and not a 'byte stream' outputStream
            * because we are sending messages
            */
            
            
            //use this stream to read things
            this.bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); 

            //use this stream to send things
            this.bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

            

            this.clientUserName = bufferedReader.readLine();
            
            System.out.println("THis is running");
                        
            //passing it into tthe arrayList clientHandlers
            clientHandlers.add(this);

            

            
        } catch(IOException e){
            closeEverything(socket, bufferedReader, bufferedWriter);
        }
    }


    @Override
    
    public void run() {
        String messageFromClient; 

        try{
            broadCastMessage("Server: " + clientUserName + " has joined the server");

            while(socket.isConnected()){
                messageFromClient = bufferedReader.readLine();
                broadCastMessage(messageFromClient);
            }
        } catch(IOException e){
                closeEverything(socket, bufferedReader, bufferedWriter); 
        } finally {
                removeClientHandler();
        }
    }
    

    //BroadsCasts a particular message from the client to other clients in the group 
    public void broadCastMessage(String messageToSend){
        for(ClientHandler clientHandler : clientHandlers){
            try{
                if(!clientHandler.clientUserName.equals(clientUserName)){
                    //Using the bufferedWriter to send The message to other participants in the group
                    clientHandler.bufferedWriter.write(messageToSend);
                    //this line indicates the use id done sending data no need to wait for new characters
                    clientHandler.bufferedWriter.newLine();
                    clientHandler.bufferedWriter.flush();
                }
            } catch(IOException e){
                closeEverything(socket, bufferedReader, bufferedWriter);
            }
        }
    }

    //to remove a client after they have exited the group 
    public void removeClientHandler(){
        clientHandlers.remove(this); 

        //braodcasting a message to other participants to show the user has left 
        broadCastMessage(clientUserName + " Has left the chat");
    }

    public void closeEverything(Socket socket, BufferedReader bufferedReader, BufferedWriter bufferedWriter ){
        //removing the client from the groupchat
        removeClientHandler();
        //closing previoiusly made connections
        try{
            /*first checking the buffered reader is not equal to null 
            * so when we call the close method we dont get a null pointer exception
            */
            if(bufferedReader != null){
                bufferedReader.close();
            }
            //Checking the bufferedWriter
            if(bufferedWriter != null){
                bufferedWriter.close();
            }
            //checking the socket
            if(socket != null){
                socket.close();
            }

        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client{
    private Socket socket; 
    private BufferedReader bufferedReader; 
    private BufferedWriter bufferedWriter; 
    private String userName; 


    public Client(Socket socket, String userName){
        try {
            this.socket = socket; 
            this.bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            this.bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));    
            this.userName = userName; 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            closeEverything(socket, bufferedReader, bufferedWriter); 
        }
        
    }

    public void sendMessage(){
        try{
            bufferedWriter.write(userName); 
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
            bufferedWriter.flush();

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 

            while(socket.isConnected()){
                String messageToSend = sc.next();
                bufferedWriter.write(userName + ": " + messageToSend);
                bufferedWriter.newLine();
                bufferedWriter.flush();
            }
            
            
        } catch(IOException e){
            closeEverything(socket, bufferedReader, bufferedWriter);
            
        }
    }

    public void listenToMessage(){
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            
            public void run(){
                String messageFromGroupChat; 

                try {
                    while(socket.isConnected()){
                        messageFromGroupChat = bufferedReader.readLine();
                        System.out.print(messageFromGroupChat); 
                    }
                    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    closeEverything(socket, bufferedReader, bufferedWriter);
                }
                

            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void closeEverything(Socket socket, BufferedReader bufferedReader, BufferedWriter bufferedWriter2){
        try{
            /*first checking the buffered reader is not equal to null 
            * so when we call the close method we dont get a null pointer exception
            */
            if(bufferedReader != null){
                bufferedReader.close();
            }
            //Checking the bufferedWriter
            if(bufferedWriter != null){
                bufferedWriter.close();
            }
            //checking the socket
            if(socket != null){
                socket.close();
            }

        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Enter User Name for the group chat: ");
        String userName = sc.nextLine(); 
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
        Client client = new Client(socket, userName); 
        
        client.listenToMessage();
        client.sendMessage();
        
        

        
    }
}
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server{
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public Server(ServerSocket serverSocket){
        this.serverSocket = serverSocket;
    }

    public void startServer(){
        try{
            /*while the server socket is not closed it will accept
            * incoming connections
            */
            while (!serverSocket.isClosed()) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("A new client has connected");

                /*each object of this class is responsible for communication with the class  
                * also imiplements runnable as each object of the class will be handled by a different 
                * thread
                */
                ClientHandler clientHandler= new ClientHandler(socket);
                
                Thread thread = new Thread(clientHandler); 
                thread.start();
                System.out.println("Thread started");
                
            }
        } catch(IOException e){

        }
    }

    public void closeServerSocket(){
        try{
            if(serverSocket != null){
                serverSocket.close();
            }
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //code runs from here
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //ServerSocket accepts a port number as param
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1234);
        Server server = new Server(serverSocket); 
        server.startServer();
    }
}




socket.isConnected()) doesn't do what you are using it for, It is not a test for peer disconnection. The correct loop is while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) { ... }.

Also you are failing to print most of the exceptions. Don't write code like this.

Thank you for your time, concerning the socket.isconnected(), are you referring to it's mention in the listenToMessage() and sendMessage() in the Client class
